# Amount of reputation until next privelege

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, privileges

Why is it that the "next privilege" bar shows the amount of privilege required for your next privilege to even be your next privilege? It makes it look as though I am a lot closer to attaining the next privilege than I really am. Take my own for example:

[image: Privileges]

I know I already have 1,000 rep! Can't the bar just display the amount I need out of 250 instead of 1250? I feel as though it would be a lot more useful in performing its task if it functioned this way.

Answer (score 11):

This is a progress bar, meaning it should show your progress towards something.

This is totally clear and useful at is it right now, changing it would create confusion.

This is also consistent with other progress displays throughout Stack Exchange, e.g. Review Badges progress:

> [image]

All of the above explains why I'm against this feature request.

Comment: My understanding of the proposal is that the progress bar will still show the progress towards something; OP just wants to shift the *starting point* from 0 to the amount of reputation required for the previous privilege. Since from privileges point of view reputation is indeed additive (once you reached some privilege at 1000 rep point you need just 250 additional to achieve another privilege at 1250 and not 1250) this in fact might make some sense.

Comment: @Wildcat well, my second argument, which is still strong, stays - "This is also consistent with other progress displays throughout Stack Exchange" as in the review badges progress example.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't quite get what kind of "consistency" you screenshot shows. Different review badges are related to the progress in different tasks, thus the progress is consistently counted from 0 for each and every review badge. But different privileges are all associated with the *same* quantity (total amount of rep) which is counted *cumulatively*, thus, the zero level for each and every privilege is not 0, but rather the amount of rep required for the previous privilege.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I'm personally fine with the way the things are done currently. But: 1) I don't understand why OP was downvoted so outrageously; 2) your argumentation seems to be week for me.

Comment: @Wildcat feel free to post new answer where you explain why you support this feature request - nothing outrageous in the downvotes, just users like me who do not agree with the request, each and his/her own reasons, I just explained my own.